# How does one get rid of screen flickering

Tags: games

Some time ago I downloaded Warzone 2100, the screen flickered and I thought it was just part of the game but the next time I went on assault cube that flickered as well (It did not flicker before warzone). Most recently Americas army began to flicker after I changed the screen revolution and now it will not stop flickering even if I restore default settings. How can I disable screen flickering? \

Update:

This all started to happen after I upgraded to 11.10

Comment: What OS, what graphics driver?

Comment: 11.0 of what? Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

You should try to explain more thoroughly the setup that you're using.  What video drivers are you using?  What type of video card is it?  What are the video settings in your game?  What are your video driver settings?  Does this happen in any other applications such as playing flash videos on full screen?

All of these things can have a direct impact on the way video is rendered and what is causing the flickering.

The first thing I would check is your driver forced settings, are they forcing v-sync (Vertical Sync)?  If not, attempt to turn it on and see if that solves your issue.  Also check this setting in the application that you're trying to run.

What refresh rate is your monitor capable of handling?  What is your refresh rate in-game set to?

With the information that's given it could be any combination of things.